# React: Map and render Table of grouped rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to map and render the following data into a series of grouped tables but I am struggling. Can anyone point me in the right direction...

Data

```
    [{
    group: "twitter",
    records : [
    {_id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM", 
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC", 
    company_ID: "1", 
    coreURL: "http://test88.com", 
    feedback: "Charles"
    },{
    _id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM", 
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC", 
    company_ID: "1", 
    coreURL: "http://test99.com", 
    feedback: "Gerry"
    }
    ]},{
    group: "linkedin",
    records : [
    {_id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM", 
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC", 
    company_ID: "1", 
    coreURL: "http://test88.com", 
    feedback: "Charles"
    },{
    _id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM", 
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC", 
    company_ID: "1", 
    coreURL: "http://test99.com", 
    feedback: "Gerry"
   }
   ]}]
```

I am trying to achieve...

```
    *Group 1*
    - Item 1
    - Item 2

    *Group 2*
    - Item 1
    - Item 2
```

I have been able to map and a render a standard dataset into a single table, but struggling with the grouped element

Comment: You already have an array of two group objects with two items in each. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i think the OP wants an object back and not an array (a sort of a dictionary)

Comment: Thanks yes I have the data in the right shape I think, but I am trying to construct a series of rows underneath a header. This will eventually tied to state such that when I change state that changes the grouping property (e.g. would then group on feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this with the following and render out each line of the grouped table in the RecordListDetail component:

```
groupedTables(){
return groupedData.map ((group, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}>
    <div>
      {group.group}
    </div>
    <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
      <tbody>
        {group.records.map ((details, index) =>
        <RecordListDetail
          key={index}
          details={details}
        />
        )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) to create a `groupBy` util and perhaps link it to the Array prototype.

```js
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
  return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
    const val = item[key];
    groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
    groups[val].push(item);
    return groups;
  }, {});
};

const data = [{
  group: "twitter",
  records: [{
    _id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM",
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
    company_ID: "1",
    coreURL: "http://test88.com",
    feedback: "Charles"
  }, {
    _id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM",
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
    company_ID: "1",
    coreURL: "http://test99.com",
    feedback: "Gerry"
  }]
}, {
  group: "linkedin",
  records: [{
    _id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM",
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
    company_ID: "1",
    coreURL: "http://test88.com",
    feedback: "Charles"
  }, {
    _id: "aMzJECeyvoLGdNzRM",
    owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
    company_ID: "1",
    coreURL: "http://test99.com",
    feedback: "Gerry"
  }]
}]

const groupedData = data.groupBy('group');
console.log(groupedData);
```

There are some libraries that already implementing this kind of methods like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: Thanks @Sag1v I have looked at lodash but really I was looking for some practical examples of how I can iterate through the dataset and either create a table per category or maybe one big table where the group header has a colspan that streatches over a few columns

Comment: I'm sorry i misunderstood your question then. i didn't realize you are asking about how to render the data, i thought you are asking how to change the data shape.

Comment: no problem. Thanks I have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: ok then, share the code that render the tables and let us know what exactly isn't working for you.